# Expected '}' Arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi

I am trying to code a BLE device and send SSID & password from a phone to the device.

But I have been checking this code for a while but I cannot find where the error is. I used Arduino IDE and VCode to check brackets but still, I cannot find them. Can somebody help me?

It is showing me that a bracket is missing.

No matter what I do, it happens every time.

```
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
  // TODO this doesn't take into account several clients being connected
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    Serial.println("BLE client connected");
  };

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    Serial.println("BLE client disconnected");
    pAdvertising->start();
  }
};

class MyCallbackHandler: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    if (value.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    Serial.println("Received over BLE: " + String((char *)&value[0]));

    // Decode data
    int keyIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < value.length(); index ++) {
      value[index] = (char) value[index] ^ (char) apName[keyIndex];
      keyIndex++;
      if (keyIndex >= strlen(apName)){
        keyIndex = 0;
      }
    }

    /** Json object for incoming data */
    JsonObject& jsonIn = jsonBuffer.parseObject((char *)&value[0]);
    if (jsonIn.success()) {
      if (jsonIn.containsKey("ssid") && jsonIn.containsKey("password") {
        ssid = jsonIn["ssid"].as<String>();
        password = jsonIn["password"].as<String>();

        Preferences preferences;
        preferences.begin("WiFiCred", false);
        preferences.putString("ssid", ssid);
        preferences.putString("password", password);
        preferences.putBool("valid", true);
        preferences.end();

        Serial.println("Received over bluetooth:");
        Serial.println("primary SSID: "+ssid+" password: "+password);
        connStatusChanged = true;
        hasCredentials = true;
      }
      else if (jsonIn.containsKey("erase")) {
        Serial.println("Received erase command");
        Preferences preferences;
        preferences.begin("WiFiCred", false);
        preferences.clear();
        preferences.end();
        connStatusChanged = true;
        hasCredentials = false;
        ssid = "";
        password = "";
      }
      else if (jsonIn.containsKey("reset")) {
        WiFi.disconnect();
        esp_restart();
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Received invalid JSON");
    }
    jsonBuffer.clear();
  };

  void onRead(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    Serial.println("BLE onRead request");
    String wifiCredentials;

    /** Json object for outgoing data */
    JsonObject& jsonOut = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    jsonOut["ssid"] = ssid;
    jsonOut["password"] = password;
    // Convert JSON object into a string
    jsonOut.printTo(wifiCredentials);

    // encode the data
    int keyIndex = 0;
    Serial.println("Stored settings: " + wifiCredentials);
    for (int index = 0; index < wifiCredentials.length(); index ++) {
      wifiCredentials[index] = (char) wifiCredentials[index] ^ (char) apName[keyIndex];
      keyIndex++;
      if (keyIndex >= strlen(apName)){ keyIndex = 0;}
    }
    pCharacteristicWiFi->setValue((uint8_t*)&wifiCredentials[0],wifiCredentials.length());
    jsonBuffer.clear();
  }
};

/**
 * initBLE
 * Initialize BLE service and characteristic
 * Start BLE server and service advertising
 */
void initBLE() {
  // Initialize BLE and set output power
  BLEDevice::init(apName);
  BLEDevice::setPower(ESP_PWR_LVL_P7);

  // Create BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  // Set server callbacks
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create BLE Service
  pService = pServer->createService(BLEUUID(SERVICE_UUID),20);

  // Create BLE Characteristic for WiFi settings
  pCharacteristicWiFi = pService->createCharacteristic(
    BLEUUID(WIFI_UUID),
    // WIFI_UUID,
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
  );
  pCharacteristicWiFi->setCallbacks(new MyCallbackHandler());

  // Start the service
  pService->start();

  // Start advertising
  pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
}

/** Callback for receiving IP address from AP */
void gotIP(system_event_id_t event) {
  isConnected = true;
  connStatusChanged = true;
}

/** Callback for connection loss */
void lostCon(system_event_id_t event) {
  isConnected = false;
  connStatusChanged = true;
}

/**
   scanWiFi
   Scans for available networks 
   and decides if a switch between
   allowed networks makes sense

   @return <code>bool</code>
          True if at least one allowed network was found
*/
bool scanWiFi() {
  /** RSSI for primary network */
  int8_t rssi;
  /** Result of this function */
  bool result = false;

  Serial.println("Start scanning for networks");

  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.enableSTA(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Scan for AP
  int apNum = WiFi.scanNetworks(false,true,false,1000);
  if (apNum == 0) {
    Serial.println("Found no networks?????");
    return false;
  }
  
  byte foundAP = 0;
  bool found = false;

  for (int index=0; index<apNum; index++) {
    String found_ssid = WiFi.SSID(index);
    Serial.println("Found AP: " + found_ssid + " RSSI: " + WiFi.RSSI(index));
    if (!strcmp((const char*) &found_ssid[0], (const char*) &ssid[0])) {
      Serial.println("Found AP");
      foundAP++;
      found = true;
      rssi = WiFi.RSSI(index);
    }
  }

  switch (foundAP) {
    case 0:
      result = false;
      break;
    case 1:
      result = true;
      break;
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Start connection to AP
 */
void connectWiFi() {
  // Setup callback function for successful connection
  WiFi.onEvent(gotIP, SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP);
  // Setup callback function for lost connection
  WiFi.onEvent(lostCon, SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED);

  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.enableSTA(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Start connection to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // Create unique device name
  createName();

  // Send some device info
  Serial.print("Build: ");
  Serial.println(compileDate);

  Preferences preferences;
  preferences.begin("WiFiCred", false);
  bool hasPref = preferences.getBool("valid", false);
  if (hasPref) {
    ssid = preferences.getString("ssid","");
    password = preferences.getString("password","");
    
    if (ssid.equals("") || password.equals("") {
      Serial.println("Found preferences but credentials are invalid");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Read from preferences:");
      Serial.println("primary SSID: "+ssid+" password: "+password);
      hasCredentials = true;
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Could not find preferences, need send data over BLE");
  }
  preferences.end();

  // Start BLE server
  initBLE();

  if (hasCredentials) {
    // Check for available AP's
    if (!scanWiFi) {
      Serial.println("Could not find any AP");
    }
    else {
      // If AP was found, start connection
      connectWiFi();
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (connStatusChanged) {
    if (isConnected) {
      Serial.print("Connected to AP: ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID());
      Serial.print(" with IP: ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
      Serial.print(" RSSI: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());
    }
    else {
      if (hasCredentials) {
        Serial.println("Lost WiFi connection");
        // Received WiFi credentials
        if (!scanWiFi) { // Check for available AP's
          Serial.println("Could not find any AP");
        }
        else { // If AP was found, start connection
          connectWiFi();
        }
      } 
    }
    connStatusChanged = false;
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Nothing changed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does this error occur? Could you post the full error message? Sometimes one is missing a different character which makes the compiler think a brace is missing

Comment: `if (jsonIn.containsKey("ssid") && jsonIn.containsKey("password") {`

Comment: debugging errors like this is trivial. from inside out you start deleting every block that is ok. at one point you'll stumble over an error. please don't expet us to do this for you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You miss a closing parenthesis in this line of code:

```
if ( jsonIn.containsKey("ssid") && jsonIn.containsKey("password") {
```

should be:

```
if ( jsonIn.containsKey("ssid") && jsonIn.containsKey("password") ) {
```

Comment: please don't answer off-topic questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic